# Capturar parámetros de la URL en el formulario a través de vista basada en clases

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-urls

Necesito pasarle unos parámetros a mi formulario para poder editar un campo de dicho formulario. Estoy trabajando con vistas basadas en clase CreateView

```
Archivo urls.py
path('crear_usuariospdnarmarios/<str:id>/<str:idag>/', login_required(CrearUsuarioPDNArmarios.as_view()), name = 'crear_usuariospdnarmarios')

Archivo views.py
class CrearUsuarioPDNArmarios(CreateView):
model : Usuariosarmarios
template_name = 'GestionPaqueteria/permisosuPDN/usuariospdnarmarios/crear_usuariospdnarmarios.html'
form_class = UsuariosarmariosForm 

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(CrearUsuarioPDNArmarios, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update(self.kwargs)  # self.kwargs contains all url conf params
    return kwargs

Archivo forms.py
class UsuariosarmariosForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    id= kwargs.pop('id')
    idag= kwargs.pop('idag')
    super(UsuariosarmariosForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

idarmario = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Armarios.objects.filter(idagencia=idag))
```

El problema es que cuando trabajo con el parámetro idag me muestra el error: NameError: name 'idag' is not defined
A qué se puede deber dicho error???

Comment: El error se debe a que defines la variable `idag` dentro del método `__init__`, y su alcance es local, ademas de que `idarmario` es un atributo de clase, lo cual hace mas imposible lo que intentas hacer. La respuesta de @Victor Villalobos puede ser una solución a tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta, cambiar el queryset de esta forma:

```py
class UsuariosarmariosForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id= kwargs.pop('id')
        idag= kwargs.pop('idag')
        self.fields['idarmario'].queryset = Armarios.objects.filter(idagencia=idag)
        super(UsuariosarmariosForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Los forms en django al igual que los modelos heredan de una Metaclase por lo que en tiempo de "Buildeo" se convierten todos los fields que tu defines en atributos de la clase con sus respectivos argumentos, específicamente a la propiedad "fields" del forms.Form, por lo que tú argumento **idag** no está inicializada en tiempo de "Buildeo" cuando django convierte los fields en propiedades de la clase.

Las metaclases son un concepto abstracto, si quieres saber cómo funcionan las metaclases mira:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python

Y acá explican como las utiliza Django:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344197/how-does-djangos-meta-class-work

Espero te sea de ayuda.